# Dependency Xvfb missing error on npm run

Tags: windows-11, wsl2, npm, xvfb, cypress

On running the command `npm run test` on ubuntu WSL-2 Windows 11. I get the following error:

> account-management-fullstack-level-2@1.0.0 test
> cypress run
>
> It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 9.7.0
>
> Your system is missing the dependency: Xvfb
>
> Install Xvfb and run Cypress again.
>
> Read our documentation on dependencies for more information:
>
> https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
>
> If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required
> dependencies installed.
>
> ---
>
> Error: spawn Xvfb ENOENT
>
> ---
>
> Platform: linux-x64 (Ubuntu - 20.04) Cypress Version: 9.7.0
> I am not sure how to go about resolving this error. Any ideas?

***Some Attempts:***
***sudo apt-get install libg
tk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb***

```
[sudo] password for ron:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.24.32-4ubuntu4).
libgtk2.0-0 set to manually installed.
libxss1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.3-1).
libxss1 set to manually installed.
libxtst6 is already the newest version (2:1.2.3-1).
xauth is already the newest version (1:1.1-0ubuntu1).
xauth set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 is to be installed
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.8+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
 xvfb : Depends: libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb`? as per the link?

Comment: I resolved the error by installing each library in a separate apt-get install command. For some it gave the same error. The command `sudo aptitude install <package-name>` resolved it along with `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on Rocky Linux 8, and installing `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` dnf package helped

```bash
dnf install -y chromium xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```